# How does the w3-total-cache plugins works with pdf documents

Tags: wordpress, w3-total-cache

I don't understand how w3 total cache, the wordpress plugin, works with PDF.
When he plugin is not activated the link to the pdf is something like

http://mywebsite.com/mydoc.pdf

and when activated

http://mywebsite.com/mydoc.x49090.pdf

Thanks for your help.